# Как сделать левый блок виджетов видимым для всех?

Tags: wordpress, wp-theme

Есть вот такая тема, правда старая. https://wordpress.org/themes/houston/
Оказывается в ней добавлен блок виджетов слева который виден только админу (может быть еще со-админам и редакторам), главное не всем.
Сам код добавления этого блока виджетов выглядит так в functions.php:

```
    <?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

/**
 * Add a new sidebar beneath the post box.
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'houston_register_sidebar' );
function houston_register_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Beneath Post Box', 'Houston' ),
        'id'            => 'beneath-post-box',
        'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>' )
    );
}


/**
 * Tweak p2
 */
add_action( 'init', 'houston_custom' );
function houston_custom() {
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'p2_iphone_style', 1000 );
}


/**
 * Add the search widget to the nav
 */
function houston_new_nav_menu_items( $items, $args ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        $homelink   = the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Search' );
        $items      = $items . $homelink;
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'houston_new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );


/**
 * Add js to the frontend
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'houston_scripts', 999 );
function houston_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'woo-p2-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fitvids', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/fitvids.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'iphone' );
}


/**
 * Add viewport meta
 */
add_action( 'wp_head', 'houston_viewport_meta' );
function houston_viewport_meta() {
?>
    <!--  Mobile viewport scale | Disable user zooming as the layout is optimised -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<?php
}


/**
 * Integrations
 * Include logic that integrates Houston with third party plugins
 */

/**
 * p2-likes
 * http://wordpress.org/plugins/p2-likes/
 */
if ( defined( 'P2LIKES_URL' ) ) {
    require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/integrations/p2-likes/p2-likes.php' );
}
```

тема вообще не имеет адекватного вида без левого блока виджетов, все сдвинуто влево.
Поэтому хотелось бы либо изменить код и сделать видимым виджеты слева всем, либо выровнять вид тех блоков что виден всем.
Пробовал изменить код на такой вариант:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
```

но виджеты снова видит опять один админ, убирал и if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;, все равно видит только админ.

- index.php страница берется из родительской темы Р2 и выглядит так:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package P2
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="sleeve_main">
 <?php if ( p2_user_can_post() && !is_archive() ) : ?>
  <?php locate_template( array( 'post-form.php' ), true ); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <div id="main">
  <h2>
   <?php if ( is_home() or is_front_page() ) : ?>

    <?php _e( 'Recent Updates', 'p2' ); ?> <?php if ( p2_get_page_number() > 1 ) printf( __( 'Page %s', 'p2' ), p2_get_page_number() ); ?>

   <?php else : ?>

    <?php printf( _x( 'Updates from %s', 'Month name', 'p2' ), get_the_time( 'F, Y' ) ); ?>

   <?php endif; ?>

   <span class="controls">
    <a href="#" id="togglecomments"> <?php _e( 'Toggle Comment Threads', 'p2' ); ?></a> | <a href="#directions" id="directions-keyboard"><?php _e( 'Keyboard Shortcuts', 'p2' ); ?></a>
   </span>
  </h2>

  <ul id="postlist">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php p2_load_entry(); ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php else : ?>

   <li class="no-posts">
       <h3><?php _e( 'No posts yet!', 'p2' ); ?></h3>
   </li>

  <?php endif; ?>
  </ul>

  <div class="navigation">
   <p class="nav-older"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'p2' ) ); ?></p>
   <p class="nav-newer"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'p2' ) ); ?></p>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- main -->

</div> <!-- sleeve -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Добрый день нужно тебе в коде смотреть в файле вывода шаблона ( там должен быть php фильтр типа if user auth тебе его просто убрать и будем всем показан тогда, если же нет то полюбому только код смотреть нужно либо сюда покажи еще код вывода и файл fuction

Comment: @Basszilla добавил в вопрос коды

Comment: Друг у тебя должно быть <?php getsidebar();?>
https://misha.blog/wordpress/sidebars.html 
По этой инструкции найди шаблон сайдбара а так же где его выводят через getsidebar и посмотри нет ли условии по типу<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    <?php getsidebar(твой сайдбар);?>
} else {
    Ничего
}
?>

Comment: Смотрел нету там такого кода уже во всех файлах и папках поискал. Где только могло быть. Вывод сайдбара таков <?php
/**
 * Sidebar template.
 *
 * @package P2
 */
?>
 <div id="sidebar">
 <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>

  <ul>
   <?php
    dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' );
   ?>
  </ul>

  <div class="clear"></div>

 </div> <!-- // sidebar -->